# If $X_n$ converges a.s. to $2$ , is $X_n$ integrable for large $n$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$.
Assume that:

- $\forall n\geq 1, \forall \omega\in \Omega, X_n(\omega)\geq 0$,
- $(X_n)$ converges almost surely to $2$.

Is is true that $E[X_n]<\infty$ for $n$ large enough ?

I don't have any leads on this one (this question comes up naturally in my research), I'm guessing that an example where $E[X_n]=\infty$ can be found...

EDIT: the third condition was implied by the a.s. convergence, I've removed it.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the expectation being finite for $n$ large enough. For example, what about $X_n = 2 + 1_{ [0, {1 \over n}]}$ on $\Omega = [0,1]$. $E X_n = 2+n$.

Comment: @copper.hat I was thinking along exactly same lines coincidentally lol. But I think the op wants $E[X_{n}]=\infty$ for all $n$ . Else $E[X_{n}]<\infty$ for all $n$ in your example. In which case might I suggest $X_{n}=2+\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$  from $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments. You can take the Probability space to be $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ .

Take $$X_{n}(x)=2+\frac{1}{x}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$$

Then $X_{n}\to 2$ pointwise, but $E[X_{n}]=\infty\,,\forall n$ .

Comment: Thank you, the $\liminf$ I had imposed initially is actually a consequence of the a.s convergence. I've edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay. I'll approve your edit.